# Error while trying to compile imported project from Mbed compiler

Tags: eclipse, arm, mbed

I have completely followed installing the GNU MCU Eclipse compiler along with the arm gnu toolchain and its complementary GCC toolchain provided in the 
[tutorial link](https://gnu-mcu-eclipse.github.io/plugins/install/).

When I want to build a project which I exported from the Mbed online compiler, I set the PATH variable in the project's properties to wherever the `where gnu-arm-none-eabi-g++` command refers. But Regarding all the instructions I followed I am still getting this compile error:

`**Error:Program "make" not found in PATH**`

Comment: Instead of setting the PATH, I think you need to add to the PATH - that is usually the way it's done with the PATH environment variable. Also, do you have `make` installed?

Comment: Yes, I have installed the windows build tools via the xpm tool (which was recommended by the writer) and I also add the path variable to my projects environment variables.

Comment: You need to find make and put it on your PATH.

Comment: I have tested that too, but still, I got a make error. I think the IDE is not well integrated with the toolchain and the build tools provided in the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is a way around in order to avoid the multi-step process for setting up the Eclipse IDE for Max devices.
The Maxim Integrated company has special eclipse neon dedicated for maxim arm processors which can be downloaded from [this link](https://www.maximintegrated.com/bin/downloadpackage).

Warning!!: when you install the arm toolchain and run the Eclipse IDE, be aware that you don't update the IDE tools and libraries via the IDE itself. However, if you want to update the libraries you can do this by the Arm cortex management app which is included in the toolchain setup.